# Is this First Answers review audit a good / unambiguous audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, first-answers

I failed [a review audit in the First Answers queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/33485051) after selecting “Share Feedback” when it’s apparently supposed to be “Looks OK”.

The post sounded vague to me and it did not cite any sources. Hence, I intended to share the “supporting information” feedback.

> **Answer needs supporting information**
>
> Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

- Why does intending to share feedback lead to me failing the audit?
- Is this considered a good / unambiguous audit?
- What would everyone intuitively have chosen?

Comment: By selecting “share feedback” that implies there was something wrong with the answer. There is nothing wrong with the answer, which has 23 upvotes, and zero downvotes. Would argue any problems that exist, have to do with the quality of the question.

Comment: @SecurityHound "needs supporting information"

Comment: Why? The answer is clear and says exactly what to do to solve the authors problem.* So selecting that option was the wrong decision.*

Comment: @SecurityHound When doing a review audit, one can't see the post's score until after they complete the audit, so OP wouldn't be able to go off of votes alone. The audits are supposed to be reviewed on the post's content alone, but then the system judges you based of whether or not you agree with the votes.

Comment: @MichaelM. - I always open up reviews in another tab. I rarely fail audits for this reason. Any failure of the answer exists with the question. If you forgive the many failures with the question, the answer is acceptable and clear and concise, and definitely answers the question.

Comment: @SecurityHound Isn't an audit where a responsible reviewer changes the action between the default review view and opening it in another tab a bad audit?

Comment: @MagnusO_O - That’s why I open all reviews in another tab, there isn’t a rule, that requires a user not to identify an audit as an audit.

Comment: @SecurityHound That's a good workaround recommendation concerning the current audit selection. Aside audits still can be good and bad ones.

Comment: Do most users find that the linked review audit is, in fact, a good review audit and would've intuitively chosen 'Looks OK'?

Answer (score 8):

I agree that this is a bad audit, but I still would have taken other action.

The answer's question isn't particularly good, but it has 37 upvotes because many other people had the same issue. Likewise, the answer isn't that good because there are ([usually](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8842/lifeboat)) no good answers to a bad question. However, the review audit system takes votes verbatim and thinks that higher score unilaterally means good post.

The issue I have with this audit is that the answer and its question doesn't make much sense unless you are having the same issue and can follow along with context. The answer/question doesn't provide much context on its own. For regular answers this is OK, someone wouldn't be looking at the answer unless they had the same issue, but for reviewers, there is no other way to get that context. Thus, I think that this is a bad audit, not necessarily a wrong audit though.

Choosing the "Share Feedback" option implies that you think the post is bad. Initially, the answer **does** look confusing, but once you look at its question it is equally confusing. In this case, one should acknowledge that the post is too confusing for those who don't have the context and should, in my opinion, skip the review task.

Comment: When that wouldn't be an audit but a normal review and everyone skips. Would that answer then stay forever in the review queue or would it be removed from the queue after a certain time, resulting in the same effect as 'looks ok'?

Comment: @MagnusO_O - The only way that answer stop being an audit is if received dozens of downvotes. The fact it received zero suggests that won’t happen.

Comment: @SecurityHound That's true for an audit. Please see my starting point 'When that wouldn't be an audit but a normal review' at above comment.

Comment: @MagnusO_O In the First Q's/ A's queues, reviews themselves don't age away, but in practice there is a cap because posts will invalidate their "first post" review item if the post becomes older than 2 weeks, or from [a few other reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369765).

Answer (score 3):

I've never used Google Play Console before, but even so I feel I would be able to follow the instructions in the answer. If you've never used GPC before and can't understand the answer, that is a good indication you should skip it. The answer had a few problems grammatically, but choosing "edit" would have passed the audit too.

You should rarely if ever use "Share Feedback". It's feedback intended for really bad answers. Reading the feedback you sent for this answer makes me wonder what "citations or documentation" the user should have provided. (The question seems to be asking about a bug in GPC.) Anyone who actually has the problem can verify in a few seconds if the answer works for them or not. If you did have more specific advice, I believe (though the behavior has varied over the years) that leaving a comment and selecting "Other Action" would also have passed the audit.

The question may not be on topic, but in that case you should cast a close vote instead.

Comment: "*It's feedback intended for really bad answers.*" The Answer is Bad Quality, sorry...! Putting a Comment in the Review Process asking to improve the Quality feels completely Legit to me... Answerer's Answer is: "*I had the same Pb, I did a Refresh, it works for me...*" => And the Crowd yelled: "**YEAH!...!. we have a HERO...!!!**" => +23 Upvotes...! // Is 'SO' really meant for that kind of "Solutions"...!? (...  and to be used for Audits...?)

Comment: @chivracq - So downvote the answer. That’s the only way the community can help get rid of the audit. I must repeat my previous thoughts, there wasn’t anything wrong, with the answer and it clearly in the context of the question answered the question

Comment: @SecurityHound, hum..., but even if OP (the Reviewer) (had) downvoted that Answer, wouldn't they have also failed the Audit, as the Audit expects a "Looks OK" or an Upvote...? (And we would still be "here", discussing if it's a good Audit or not...) // And "Bad/Low Quality" doesn't mean that the Answer is "wrong or incorrect" anyway...